# How to create Inherited Member-Type in Umbraco 6.X?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, umbraco

for example I want to create two types of users 
1. **Teacher**
2. **Student**

Teacher having properties of **Fname**, **Lname** and **Salary** made from a MemberType "**CollegeMember**"

I want to create student user with the properties **Fname** and **Lname** only.
So is it possible to create new Member type with using properties of old member type or has any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? Are you using the built in membership management of Umbraco?

Comment: I am using Umbraco 6.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member objects do not quite work like that in Umbraco. You can not inherited member objects in the same way that you can inherit document types or media types.

I would simply create two independent user types here with the properties you require. If you desperately want the inheritance, you could implement your own membership provider or extension to the API, but even then the inheritance would not be visible in Umbraco, only at the code level. In  Umbraco the member types would still appear as independent objects. So it seems like little gain.

Comment: Thanks Digbyswift, so we have to create two different Member Types (Mandatory).